# Returns a string instead of XML

Tags: php, xml, sqlsrv

I have a SQL query that returns a XML string. It works. However, I just moved to a windows php server(from a linux one) and I can no longer get the xml string from the database. It just comes out as one big string(not in xml format) so I cannot parse through all the data.

```
$query = "SELECT s FROM returnXML('id') FOR XML AUTO, TYPE;";   

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

if(sqlsrv_fetch($stmt) !== false) {
    $xml = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, 0);
    echo stream_get_contents($xml);
    var_dump($xml);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. With the current code. It prints the data(all crossed out though..) and then 'resource(5) of type (stream)'

Thanks!

Comment: Could you join a var_dump an outputted element of your query in order to make us able to help you ?

Comment: Instead of outputting '<order><type>1</type><id>2</id><info>2 boxes of paper</info></order>' it outputs '122 boxes of paper'

Comment: And what is stored in your php admin ? are the tags in the varchar containing it or they were stripped already ?

Comment: If I run my query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio it gives my the xml string with the tags. However in php it returns the xml string with no tags(not sure if thats what you mean or not)

Comment: how you watch the result? if in browser, ask for page source

Comment: Yes in a browser. What do you mean for page source?

Comment: browser does not show tags only value. add `echo "<pre>";` before var_dump. Maybe...

Comment: That's what i was asking johny. For the page source : right click on the page => view source. Tell us if the tags are in the html source.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced code with

```
if (sqlsrv_fetch($stmt) !== false) {
    $xml_res    = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, 0);
    $xml_string = stream_get_contents($xml_res);
    $xml        = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
 }
```

`$xml` is now a php variable that has the xml data in it as type [**SimpleXMLElement**](http://php.net/class.simplexmlelement).